# Mpdf unable to print euro symbol (€)

Tags: php, pdf, symbols, mpdf, euro

I'm using **mpdf** to convert a table in html to pdf.

This table includes **euro symbols** (but may contain other currency symbols in the future) the thing is, although I set mpdf charset to utf-8, it keeps printing either (**â‚¬**) or (**¬**) symbols (no brackets).

This is what I have tried so far:

- using utf8_encode and decode functions.
- Both windows-1252 and iso-8859-15 encoding (mpdf charset).
  different ways to write the same character (€ €, €)

Here is my code so far:

```
$mpdf= new mpdf('utf-8', array(210,320));
$mpdf->AddPage("L");
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'utf-8';

$mpdf->WriteHTML( utf8_encode("test &euro; €, &#8364;"), 2);
//OUTPUT
$mpdf->Output("test.pdf",'F');
echo $pdf_name;
```

As a result i get:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUpHi.png][1]

Comment: `&#8364;` for `€` ?

Comment: Does `htmlentities` help?

Comment: I have already tried htmlentities and it didn't work

Comment: &#8364; was wrong, my bad

Comment: @M.Villanueva `&#8364;` is the correct HTML entity for `€`.  Try changing `test &euro; €, &#8364;` to `test &euro; &#8364;, &#8364;`.

Comment: I just tried it but the problem seems to be the encoding not the character

Comment: For me `&euro;` works fine on versions `7+`;

Comment: I'm using version 6.0 and I cant change it

Comment: I just tried with next code (mpdf 8): 

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('&euro; €, &#8364;');
    $mpdf->Output('F');

And all symbols shows as expected in generated PDF-file. Maybe you should upgrade mpdf package? BTW your code will not working with 8.0.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot upgrade

Comment: I just checked with 6.0 and your code and two of them works: test "&euro; €, &#8364;" => "€ â¬, €"

Comment: I've just uploaded an image of the output I'm getting

Comment: What's the behavior without the `utf8_encode`? What character set do you start out with?

Comment: without utf8_encode -> test ¬ ¬

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was to upgrade to 7.1.