# Download pdf file in php(yii2) using mpdf is not support "₹" symbol

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

"₹" symbol not show in pdf after download it i  was change so many font but its not working what can i do for it ....

this is for my font style  in mpdf

```
$this->fontdata = array(
"dejavusanscondensed" => array(
    'R' => "DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf",
    'B' => "DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf",
    'I' => "DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf",
    'BI' => "DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf",
    ),
"dejavusans" => array(
    'R' => "DejaVuSans.ttf",
    'B' => "DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf",
    'I' => "DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf",
    'BI' => "DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf",
    ),
"dejavuserif" => array(
    'R' => "DejaVuSerif.ttf",
    'B' => "DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf",
    'I' => "DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf",
    'BI' => "DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf",
    ),
"dejavuserifcondensed" => array(
    'R' => "DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf",
    'B' => "DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf",
    'I' => "DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf",
    'BI' => "DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf",
    ),
"dejavusansmono" => array(
    'R' => "DejaVuSansMono.ttf",
    'B' => "DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf",
    'I' => "DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf",
    'BI' => "DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf",
    ),
but its not working in mpdf old version
```

There is my code

```
 $path = \Yii::getAlias("@vendor/MPDF/mpdf.php");
    require_once($path);
    $mpdf = new \mPDF();
    
    $mpdf->packTableData = true;
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list
        $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
    $mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.2;
    $mpdf->simpleTables = true;
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($table);
    
    $mpdf->Output('payslip.pdf', 'D');
```

[its look like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0LRm.png)

Comment: It's might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116676/mpdf-unable-to-print-euro-symbol-%E2%82%AC

Answer (score 0):

It's related to fonts. you should make sure that you imported correct fonts.

Comment: which font you suggest become i use deferent font like dejavu sans

Comment: try this:

<p style="font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;">₹</p>